# Why does software interrupts sets interrupt lines of a process to voltage high

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu, processor, microprocessors

I learned that, whenever hardware interrupt occurs, it sets interrupt line of a processor to voltage high(or low, depends on processor architecture), to make cpu stop what it was doing and serve the interrupt request.
But why same thing happens in case of software interrupt. I mean why to set those interrupt pins of processor to voltage high, why cant OS handles software interrupt as a function call, for example perform steps: 1. save current state,2. Load instruction pointer with memory address of interrupt service routine.Why does software interrupt needs to go that low to get served?

Answer (score 1):

Software interrupts need not be mapped to any hardware pins.

For example, RSTx software interrupts in 8085 don't have any hardware pins and they are used to alter the program flow.

One big difference would be: Interrupt routines execute in privileged mode whereas functions don't. This is one of the use case of software interrupts to switch from user mode to privilege mode.